# Выровнять текст с помощью CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Нужно переместить данные цифры(с фото) под checkbox'ы по центру.

```css
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 95px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .2s;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  background: #7F8C9A;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  background: #34495E;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  background: #39D2B4;
  top: 0;
  left: 51px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label .ui:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label .ui:before {
  content: "0";
  left: 46px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .ui:after {
  content: "1";
  color: #39D2B4;
  margin-top: 3px;
  left: 12px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:focus+label:before {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open sans", "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #7F8C9A;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
<label for="test1"><span class="ui"></span>1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
<label for="test2"><span class="ui"></span>2</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="test3" />
<label for="test3"><span class="ui"></span>4</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="test4" />
<label for="test4"><span class="ui"></span>8</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="test5" />
<label for="test5"><span class="ui"></span>16</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="test6" />
<label for="test6"><span class="ui"></span>32</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="test7" />
<label for="test7"><span class="ui"></span>64</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="test8" />
<label for="test8"><span class="ui"></span>128</label>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А так надо, что бы цифры были вынесены из `span`? Или это какая-то особая магия?

Comment: добавьте полностью ваш [mcve], тут надо править ваши стили, а вы их не показываете, с нуля их тут вам писать вряд ли будут

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте, прежде всего я бы либо убрал тэги span, либо поместил значения внутрь их. Но другого кода я не вижу, утверждать не буду.
Дайте всем чекбоксам margin: 0 auto. Те в свою очередь слева и справа получат внешние отступы и отцентрируются. А если нужно, чтобы отцентровка происходила вместе с label запишите чекбоксы и их лэйблы под один тэг. Например li чекбоксы, лейбл /li если вы создадите список. Или же можно использовать div